# Revit API. How can I get bounding box for several elements?

Tags: geometry, revit-api, revit

I need to find an outline for many elements (>100'000 items). Target elements come from a `FilteredElementCollector`. As usual I'm looking for the fastest possible way.

For now I tried to iterate over all elements to get its `BoudingBox.Min` and `BoudingBox.Max` and find out `minX`, `minY`, `minZ`, `maxX`, `maxY`, `maxZ`. It works pretty accurate but takes too much time.

---

The problem is described above is a part of a bigger one.
I need to find all the intersections of ducts, pipes and other curve-based elements from a link model with walls, ceilings, columns, etc. in the general model and then place openings in a intersection.

I tried to use a combination of `ElementIntersectElement` filter and  `IntersectSolidAndCurve` method to find a part of curve inside element.

First with an `ElementIntersectElement` I tried to reduce a collection for further use of `IntersectSolidAndCurve` .`IntersectSolidAndCurve` takes two argument: solid and curve and have to work in two nested one in the other loops. So, it takes for 54000 walls (after filtering) and 18000 pipes in my case 972'000'000 operation.

With the number of operations 10 ^ 5, the algorithm shows an acceptable time.
I decided to reduce the number of elements by dividing the search areas by levels. This works well for high-rise buildings, but still bad for extended low structures. I decided to divide the building by length, but I did not find a method that finds boundaries for several elements (the whole building).

I seem to go in a wrong way. Is there are right way to make it with revit api instrument

Comment: I updated the question, but the subject has changed a little bit. Do I need to open a new question or continue the discussion here?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggestion. I will grab your formulation as is and edit it for a blog post, if that is OK for you. I'll send you a draft to check for correctness. Then we can point to the blog post for the full edited question and answer, if you like. I do not think a new question is required.

Comment: Of course, Jeremy, you can use this piece of code if it's helpful. I will be happy if it helps someone else. It would be great if such a method were available in revit api out of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find boundaries we can take advantage of the binary search idea.

The difference from the classic binary search algorithm is there is no an array, and we should find two number instead of a one.

Elements in Geometry space could be presented as a 3-dimensional sorted array of XYZ points.

Revit api provides excellent `Quick Filter`: `BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter` that takes an instance of an `Outline`

So, let’s define an area that includes all the elements for which we want to find the boundaries. For my case, for example 500 meters, and create `min` and `max` point for the initial outline

```
    double b = 500000 / 304.8;
    XYZ min = new XYZ(-b, -b, -b);
    XYZ max = new XYZ(b, b, b);
```

Below is an implementation for one direction, however, you can easily use it for three directions by calling and feeding the result of the previous iteration to the input

```
     double precision = 10e-6 / 304.8;
     var bb = new BinaryUpperLowerBoundsSearch(doc, precision);

     XYZ[] rx = bb.GetBoundaries(min, max, elems, BinaryUpperLowerBoundsSearch.Direction.X);
     rx = bb.GetBoundaries(rx[0], rx[1], elems, BinaryUpperLowerBoundsSearch.Direction.Y);
     rx = bb.GetBoundaries(rx[0], rx[1], elems, BinaryUpperLowerBoundsSearch.Direction.Z);
```

The `GetBoundaries` method returns two `XYZ` points: lower and upper, which change only in the target direction, the other two dimensions remain unchanged

```
    public class BinaryUpperLowerBoundsSearch
    {
        private Document doc;

        private double tolerance;
        private XYZ min;
        private XYZ max;
        private XYZ direction;

        public BinaryUpperLowerBoundsSearch(Document document, double precision)
        {
            doc = document;
            this.tolerance = precision;
        }

        public enum Direction
        {
            X,
            Y,
            Z
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Searches for an area that completely includes all elements within a given precision.
        /// The minimum and maximum points are used for the initial assessment. 
        /// The outline must contain all elements.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minPoint">The minimum point of the BoundBox used for the first approximation.</param>
        /// <param name="maxPoint">The maximum point of the BoundBox used for the first approximation.</param>
        /// <param name="elements">Set of elements</param>
        /// <param name="axe">The direction along which the boundaries will be searched</param>
        /// <returns>Returns two points: first is the lower bound, second is the upper bound</returns>
        public XYZ[] GetBoundaries(XYZ minPoint, XYZ maxPoint, ICollection<ElementId> elements, Direction axe)
        {
            // Since Outline is not derived from an Element class there 
            // is no possibility to apply transformation, so
            // we have use as a possible directions only three vectors of basis 
            switch (axe)
            {
                case Direction.X:
                    direction = XYZ.BasisX;
                    break;
                case Direction.Y:
                    direction = XYZ.BasisY;
                    break;
                case Direction.Z:
                    direction = XYZ.BasisZ;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            // Get the lower and upper bounds as a projection on a direction vector
            // Projection is an extention method
            double lowerBound = minPoint.Projection(direction);
            double upperBound = maxPoint.Projection(direction);

            // Set the boundary points in the plane perpendicular to the direction vector. 
            // These points are needed to create BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter when IsContainsElements calls.
            min = minPoint - lowerBound * direction;
            max = maxPoint - upperBound * direction;


            double[] res = UpperLower(lowerBound, upperBound, elements);
            return new XYZ[2]
            {
                res[0] * direction + min,
                res[1] * direction + max,
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if there are any elements contains in the segment [lower, upper]
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True if any elements are in the segment</returns>
        private ICollection<ElementId> IsContainsElements(double lower, double upper, ICollection<ElementId> ids)
        {
            var outline = new Outline(min + direction * lower, max + direction * upper);
            return new FilteredElementCollector(doc, ids)
                .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
                .WherePasses(new BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter(outline))
                .ToElementIds();
        }


        private double[] UpperLower(double lower, double upper, ICollection<ElementId> ids)
        {
            // Get the Midpoint for segment mid = lower + 0.5 * (upper - lower)
            var mid = Midpoint(lower, upper);

            // Сheck if the first segment contains elements 
            ICollection<ElementId> idsFirst = IsContainsElements(lower, mid, ids);
            bool first = idsFirst.Any();

            // Сheck if the second segment contains elements 
            ICollection<ElementId> idsSecond = IsContainsElements(mid, upper, ids);
            bool second = idsSecond.Any();

            // If elements are in both segments 
            // then the first segment contains the lower border 
            // and the second contains the upper
            // ---------**|***--------
            if (first && second)
            {
                return new double[2]
                {
                    Lower(lower, mid, idsFirst),
                    Upper(mid, upper, idsSecond),
                };
            }

            // If elements are only in the first segment it contains both borders. 
            // We recursively call the method UpperLower until 
            // the lower border turn out in the first segment and 
            // the upper border is in the second
            // ---*****---|-----------
            else if (first && !second)
                return UpperLower(lower, mid, idsFirst);

            // Do the same with the second segment
            // -----------|---*****---
            else if (!first && second)
                return UpperLower(mid, upper, idsSecond);

            // Elements are out of the segment
            // ** -----------|----------- **
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Segment is not contains elements. Try to make initial boundaries wider", "lower, upper");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Search the lower boundary of a segment containing elements
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Lower boundary</returns>
        private double Lower(double lower, double upper, ICollection<ElementId> ids)
        {
            // If the boundaries are within tolerance return lower bound
            if (IsInTolerance(lower, upper))
                return lower;

            // Get the Midpoint for segment mid = lower + 0.5 * (upper - lower)
            var mid = Midpoint(lower, upper);

            // Сheck if the segment contains elements 
            ICollection<ElementId> idsFirst = IsContainsElements(lower, mid, ids);
            bool first = idsFirst.Any();

            // ---*****---|-----------
            if (first)
                return Lower(lower, mid, idsFirst);
            // -----------|-----***---
            else
                return Lower(mid, upper, ids);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Search the upper boundary of a segment containing elements
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Upper boundary</returns>
        private double Upper(double lower, double upper, ICollection<ElementId> ids)
        {
            // If the boundaries are within tolerance return upper bound
            if (IsInTolerance(lower, upper))
                return upper;

            // Get the Midpoint for segment mid = lower + 0.5 * (upper - lower)
            var mid = Midpoint(lower, upper);

            // Сheck if the segment contains elements 
            ICollection<ElementId> idsSecond = IsContainsElements(mid, upper, ids);
            bool second = idsSecond.Any();

            // -----------|----*****--
            if (second)
                return Upper(mid, upper, idsSecond);
            // ---*****---|-----------
            else
                return Upper(lower, mid, ids);
        }

        private double Midpoint(double lower, double upper) => lower + 0.5 * (upper - lower);
        private bool IsInTolerance(double lower, double upper) => upper - lower <= tolerance;

    }
```

Projection is an extention method for vector to determine the length of projection one vector for another

```
    public static class PointExt
    {
        public static double Projection(this XYZ vector, XYZ other) =>
            vector.DotProduct(other) / other.GetLength();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, what you describe is the proper approach and the only way to do it. However, there may be many possibilities to optimise your code. The Building Coder provides various utility functions that may help. For instance, to [determine the bounding box of an entire family](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/03/family-bounding-box-and-aec-hackathon-munich.html#3). Many more in [The Building Coder samples `Util` module](https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples/blob/master/BuildingCoder/BuildingCoder/Util.cs). Search there for "bounding box". I am sure they can be further optimised as well for your case. For instance, you may be able to extract all the `X` coordinates from all the individual elements' bounding box `Max` values and use a generic `Max` function to determine their maximum in one single call instead of comparing them one by one. [Benchmark your code](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/01/timer-code-for-benchmarking.html) to discover optimisation possibilities and analyse their effect on the performance. Please do share your final results for others to learn from. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to Jeremy for advice and input on this issue. I published my final result above and did some research on performance and accuracy. The code in my answer processed in 3-5 seconds / 100'000 elements and works accurate in most cases. However, there are cases where the ```BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter``` filter the item when it does not cross the ```Outline```. This happens if there is invisible geometry in the family. There are other possible reasons that I have not yet found. More tests need to be done anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your appreciation and sharing your interesting code. Using the built-in Revit filtering mechanisms will definitely be a lot faster than anything you can achieve in .NET, outside Revit memory. However, I do not yet understand how you can use this to achieve the goal you describe above. I thought you needed the collective bounding box of all elements. You, however, seem to have an input variable of 500 meters and o be checking whether that contains all the elements. Can you please explain the exact use of this algorithm, and the exact input and output data? Thank you!

Comment: Jeremy, you're absolutely right. The minimum and maximum points in 3d-space are fed to the input to the method, so that all the elements are inside the outline built on that points, then we find the extreme points along x y z. The output is 2 outline points. I updated my question to be more precise